# How to set resource URL for GraphServiceClient to fetch Groups?

Tags: .net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to fetch AD groups from the Graph API using the `groups:src1` endpoint value that I receive from `_claims_sources` in the [JWT access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens).

My client is using Client Credentials and can fetch info for all users and groups in the AD.

This is how I set it up:

```
private async Task<IList<Group>> GetUserGroupsAsync(string endpoint)
{
    // Endpoint is from the claims in a previous OIDC request

    // Setup a client if it does not exist
    PrepareGraphApiClient();

    // I can fetch my groups using the methods in the client
    // var groupPage = await graphServiceClient.Me.MemberOf.Request().GetAsync();

    // This is where I would like to use the resource URL received from the
    // claims I receive in a previous OIDC request
    var groupPageFromUrl = ???

    ...
}

private void PrepareGraphApiClient()
{
    if (graphServiceClient != null) return;

    try
    {
        AuthenticationContext authority = new AuthenticationContext(oidcOptions.Authority);
        ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(oidcOptions.ClientId, oidcOptions.ClientSecret);

        var graphApiResource = "https://graph.microsoft.com";
        AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = authority.AcquireTokenAsync(graphApiResource, clientCredential).Result;

        graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
            async requestMessage =>
            {
                // Add token to outgoing requests
                requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
                    new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authenticationResult.AccessToken);
            }));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.LogDebug($"Could not create the graph client {ex}");
        throw;
    }
}
```

Can I use the resource URL from the claims with the GraphServiceClient or do I have to set up an HttpClient to make the request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The endpoint identified in `_claim_sources.src1` is for Azure AD Graph, so the token you use needs to be for the Azure AD Graph API (`https://graph.windows.net`), not for Microsoft Graph (`https://graph.microsoft.com`). That also means you can't use the Microsoft Graph SDK, as the API requests and responses are fundamentally different.

You have two options:

1. (Recommended) Use the fact that an endpoint is given only as an indication that you have to do the lookup, and make an *equivalent* call to Microsoft Graph using the Microsoft Graph SDK:

   ```cs
   var memberOfIds = await graphServiceClient
           .Users[userObjectId]                          # from the 'oid' in access token
           .GetMemberObjects(securityEnabledOnly: true) # true if groupMembershipClaims is "SecurityGroup", false if it's "All"
           .Request()
           .PostAsync();
   ```
2. Use the endpoint given and build your own requests to Microsoft Graph using (for example) HttpClient. A quick'n'dirty example:

   ```cs
   using (var client = new HttpClient())
   {
       # Always get the token right before you use it. ADAL will take care of getting a new one
       # if needed, or using an existing cached token if not.
       authenticationResult = 
           authority.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.windows.net", clientCredential)
       client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = 
           new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);

       # Make the API request to Azure AD Graph. Note we have to include the api-version and
       # the request body.
       HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(
           $"{src}?api-version=1.6", new StringContent(
               "{'securityEnabledOnly': true}", # true if groupMembershipClaims is "SecurityGroup", false if it's "All"
               UnicodeEncoding.UTF8,
               "application/json"));
       if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
       {
           # Note we're deserializing as if it were a Microsoft Graph response to getMemberObjects,
           # rather than an Azure AD Graph response. Though it works, this is somewhat risky, and
           # it would be more correct to explicitly define the form of an Azure AD Graph response.
           var memberOfIds = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DirectoryObjectGetMemberObjectsCollectionResponse>(
               await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()).Value;
       }
   }
   ```

As a side note, I notice that you have the call to acquire a token *outside* of the `DelegateAuthenticationProvider` you've given to the Microsoft Graph library. You should put the `AcquireTokenAsync` call *inside*, so that it retrieves a fresh token for each and every Microsoft Graph request. The library (ADAL) will take care of using a cached token (if one is available), or making a new token request (if none are available or if those available are expired). Something like this:

```cs
    graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
        async requestMessage =>
        {
            // Get fresh token
            AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = 
                await authority.AcquireTokenAsync(graphApiResource, clientCredential);

            // Add token to outgoing requests
            requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
                new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authenticationResult.AccessToken);
        }));
```

Comment: What a great answer, thank you! I do wonder why the `securityEnabledOnly` flag is false in #1 and true in #2 though? I am currently trying something like this: `var groupPage = await graphServiceClient.Users[oid].GetMemberGroups(true).Request()..PostAsync();` to retrieve the groups that the user is member of.

Comment: Because I just made those up. The actual value should depend on what you've set your `groupMembershipClaims` to in your app manifest. If it's "SecurityGroup", then you should use `true`. If it's "All", you should use `false`. (I'll edit for consistency.)

Comment: Great! It was tricky to find an example on the web covering this use case. Most use the `Me` endpoint and user specific access tokens and not client credentials. Now there is one :)

Comment: Also, note that if what you want is to identify if the user is a member of a given known list of group IDs, you may want to use [checkMemberGroups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-checkmembergroups?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs) instead. It's slightly more performant, and will work even if the user is a member of more then 4K groups.

Comment: The use case is actually to find out if the user is member of a specific group but I am stuck in `YAGNI`.